# Disable showing links of <a> element on hover

Tags: html, css, angular

When I hover over on any website's `a` element, I get a link in left bottom corner. For example, when I move cursor on Stackoverflow's logo I get Stackoverflow's URL in corner:

[image]

Is it possible to disable this URL in the corner using css / html? I am using Angular 5 in project so if there is an Angular feature that does, please let me know. Thanks for answers.

Comment: I assume this is a browser function and it gives some transparency to the user so I doubt you can remove it.

Comment: @Thijn hi, when you check facebook's web messenger you saw that functionality is disabled on thread's hover, and threads are <a> elements too.

Comment: Why would you want to hide this? If anything, it's *better* to have this.

Comment: @IngoBürk this url info is overlaping some content in application which should be visible

Comment: You can just make it a button with a click handler, but I would just like to point out that actual links are more accessible and SEO-friendly.

Answer (score 2):

The preview is rendered by the browser and you can't control it. The only solution would be to use another tag with a similar style and functionality, for example:

```
<span class="link" onclick="window.open('http://website.com','_blank');">Website</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `button` with attribute `routerLink`, it will not display the URL on hover. It could be written as:

```
<button [routerLink]="['/register']">Sign Up</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's about angular, you can just do this instead:

```
<button (click)="routeToOtherPage()">Link</button>
```

with

```
routeToOtherPage() {
  this.router.navigate(["/other-page"]);
}
```

You can also write your own directive to inline this, something along the lines of this:

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[clickRouterLink]"
})
export class ClickRouterLinkDirective {
  @Input()
  private clickRouterLink: any | any[];

  @HostListener("click")
  public handleLinkClicked() {
    // Crude check for whether an array has been provided.
    // You might want to make this better (or even compare with the implementation of routerLink).
    const route = this.clickRouterLink && typeof this.clickRouterLink.length === "number"
      ? this.clickRouterLink
      : [this.clickRouterLink];

    this.router.navigate(route);
  }

  constructor(private router: Router) {}
}
```

And then

```
<button clickRouterLink="events">Link</button>
<button [clickRouterLink]="['events', event.id]">Link</button>
```